How do I change the default PO Type
I am trying to change the default value of the PO Type field.  I have tried the following and none of them have worked.

Override the FieldDefaulting event in POOrderEntry graph extension:

protected void POOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting baseHandler)
{
   if (baseHandler != null)
        baseHandler(cache, e);

   e.NewValue = POOrderType.ProjectDropShip;
            
}



Modified the screen field:

[PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
[PXDefault(POOrderType.ProjectDropShip)]
[POOrderType.List()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = true)]
[PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
protected virtual void POOrder_OrderType_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
}



Modified the field in the customization project:

enter image description here
Is there something that I am missing.  None of these approaches have changed the default value of the PO Type.  Thank you in advance for any assistance

I just copied/pasted your above into an extension of POOrderEntry, published, and it looks like it worked.  When I go to add a new PO, the type is Project Drop Ship.  What version are you on?
]
namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    protected void POOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting baseHandler)
    {
       if (baseHandler != null)
            baseHandler(cache, e);
    
       e.NewValue = POOrderType.ProjectDropShip;
                
    }
    #endregion
  }
}


Thank you Patrick.  I am using 23.206.0006.  I found out a little more:  When I click on the 'plus'/add button on the GI/list screen, it does NOT work.  However, once the entry screen is open, if I click refresh, it works.  Also if the entry screen is open and I click the 'plus'/add button, it works.  For some reason it does not work from the GI.  Thank you.
